# How to get Nginx Reverse Proxy to understand any path/folders/file.types

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

Problem:
Load balance

Main NGINX:
`https://example.com/game-cs/match-34/hls/streamingfile.type`

We want to Reverse traffic with NGINX to another URL or IP:
http://example.com/AnyPath/AnyFileType

We want when the client make a request for:
Location 1 https://example-or-ip/Loc1/game-cs/match-34/hls/streamingfile.m3u8 (or any path requested) reversed to: https://example.com/game-cs/match-34/hls/streamingfile.m3u8 (or any path requested)

Location 2: https://example-or-ip/Loc2/game-cs/match-34/hls/streamingfile.m3u8 (or any path requested) reversed to: https://example.com/game-cs/match-34/hls/streamingfile.m3u8 (or any path requested)

I already tried some Nginx Reverse Proxies config.:

```
location ~* \.(m3u8|ts)$ {
       rewrite    /([^/]+) /$1 break; //Also tried last;
       proxy_cache off;
       expires -1;
       proxy_pass https://example.com/$1;
       }
```

`try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`

```
location ~ ^/$ {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_pass example.com/$1;
       }
```